# Excel VBA: How to know the Zoom of another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the Zoom level of Sheet 2 to be the same as Sheet 1. I know I can do this:

```
Dim Zoom1 As Integer 
 
Sheet1.Activate 
Zoom1 = ActiveWindow.Zoom
Sheet2.Activate
ActiveWindow.Zoom = Zoom1
```

But since Sheet 2 will be the active sheet when this code is run, I'd really like a method that doesn't activate or select Sheet 1 in the process. But Zoom seems to depend on the window, not the sheet, and I can't find a way to identify the window in which Sheet 1 resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible. You have to activate the sheet before you can change the zoom level, since it's a property of the window and not the sheet. From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834952.aspx) documentation:

> This function affects only the sheet that's currently active in the
>   window. To use this property on other sheets, you must first activate
>   them.